# Remove Contactor Noise from Load Cell Reading

Tags: adc, filter, load-cell

I have connected my ADS1231 with STM32F030R8T6 as shown in the attached image.[image]

I have given 3.3 V power to both micro controller and adc. I am connecting load cells and i am getting satisfactory readings. I am powering my smps that gives me 15VDC and .5mA output.

The problem - Whenever the contactor switches or whenever contactor consinously switches besides my device there is a fluctuation in load cell readings. I am giving 230 VAC to my device and contactor from common point.
I have measured the voltage using the multimeter and it is stable. I have also measured the millivolts on the S+ and S- line of the load cell and they are also stable. I don't know why there is fluctuations in my readings as soon as contactor starts switching.

Any advice will be of great help. I can also upload the schematic if needed.

Comment: There is clearly interference, but without detailed circuit diagrams and pictures of the layout and position of the devices it is difficult to take this much further. For example, are all offboard connections shielded?

Comment: I will try to send u PCB design... May be that can make the picture clear...

Comment: Well, you can average multiple samples. It will help reduce the noise.

Comment: Done that thing.... Averaging is not the issue...

Comment: I have posted the schematic on this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RKPLfJoqGsbsIyMhijQieJOZ36N0rMWd